# How to programmatically push a new page modally on top of a children of a tabbed page in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I'm having a requirement where I click a button then I need to initialise the tab and its children, and also I need to push a new page on top of this, which shouldn't show the tabs below, and when I press back it should go back to the previous tabbed page with the children being active from where I navigated from

I know that I can do this by

```
CurrentPage = Children[2];
```

This would give me the result of navigating to the specific child of a tabbed page, but how can I navigate to a page further is something I'm not able to figure out

Comment: Did you try the current page setting in the appearing of the tapped page?

Comment: CurrentPAge setting works for the children of the tabbed page, but how can i push one page on top the tabbed page that's my problem, cause the child page can load normally and also in a special case where the button is clicked

Comment: Did you try the insert method of tappedPage.Children? like this.mypage.Children.Insert(0, new ContentPage());

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the problem? By pushing a new page, do you mean like a dialog pop up? or navigating which can mean pushing a new page on the navigation stack.

Comment: @GanesanVG, yea but i don't need it to act as a child, i need it to act as a content page and when clicking on back it should go to the tabbed page

Comment: @javachipper pushing a new page on top of the Tabbed Page, i hope i'm making sense

Comment: You mean navigate with the new page over the tabbed page. Yes, then you can use Navigation.PushAsync. And when you click the back button it should be back to tabbed page.

Comment: Have you tried navigating to another page? like await Navigation.PushAsync(new NextPage()); or navigating to a modal: await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NextPage());

Comment: so stupid of me, normal pushasync did the trick, thanks guys :)

Comment: @Venky So you solved your issue now?

Comment: it did @CherryBu-MSFT